Issue concercing cookie setting in django on browser, works fine on postman
I am experiencing an issue, I am using django 5 for my backend and nuxt 3 for my frontend.
I have this view in django:
@action(detail=False, methods=['POST'])
    def login(self,request):
        username = request.data['username']
        password = request.data['password']
        user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            sessionid = request.session.session_key
            return Response({'message': "Logged in!", 'sessionid': sessionid})
        else:
            return Response({'message': "Invalid credentials provided",'username': username, 'password': password}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

And when I do a post request with the proper credentials on postman, I get a 200 OK response, with the cookies being set. On the frontend I also get a 200 OK response and the set_cookie response headers for both the sessionid and csrftoken are there. However in all subsequent requests, the request cookies tab is empty and there is no 'cookie' header.
I had solved this issue, at least I thought and was able to get the sessionid cookie to be set after changing some of it's settings. However the csrftoken was still not being set despite me giving it the same settings. During the process of trying to get the csrftoken to work, the sessionid stopped being set. I tried reverting it's settings back to how it were, that didn't work so I figured I must've misremembered how the setting was correctly, so I tried every combination of values for the settings I had, to no luck.
The settings I added were:
# CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=['http://localhost:3000']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'Accept',
    'Accept-Encoding',
    'Authorization',
    'Content-Type',
    'Cookie',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

However the most important ones are the SESSION_COOKIE settings. I remember having to set samesite to 'None' so that my requests could use the sessionid cookie without being on the same domain as the backend, then I added the secure setting as true because I was getting errors without it. After that it worked for a while, but then it stopped so I toyed around with the httponly setting, worked again and now its stopped working again. I toyed around with the secure and httponly settings a bit more to no avail. I tried switching the domain 4 times, with either 'localhost', 'localhost:3000', '127.0.0.1' or '127.0.0.1:8000' as the value. Really hoping for some advice on what I could do.

It seems you’re facing a common issue with cookie handling in Django when dealing with cross-origin requests. The SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE setting to ‘None’ is indeed necessary for cross-origin requests to send cookies, but it also requires the SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE to be True, which means that the cookies will only be sent over HTTPS. Since you’re working locally, this might not be the case, and thus, the cookies may not be sent.

Ensure HTTPS:

If you’re not using HTTPS locally, you can either set up a local SSL certificate or use a service like ngrok to create a secure tunnel to your local server.

Check Browser Settings:

Modern browsers enforce strict policies on cross-origin cookies. Ensure your browser is configured to accept third-party cookies, especially when SAMESITE=None.

Verify Frontend Configuration:

In your Nuxt.js application, make sure that credentials are included with every request. This is typically done by setting credentials: 'include' in your AJAX request or fetch API call.

Django Settings:

Review your Django settings:

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

should be set to allow cookies to be included in cross-origin requests.

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS

should include the origins you expect to serve.

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE

should be True if SAMESITE=None, but you’ll need to ensure you’re using HTTPS.

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY

= True is good for security, as it prevents JavaScript from accessing the cookie, but make sure this is not preventing your frontend from reading the cookie if needed.

Inspect Response Headers:

Check the Set-Cookie headers in the response to ensure they’re being set correctly with the appropriate flags.

Test with Different Browsers:

Sometimes, specific browser settings or extensions can interfere with cookie handling. Try testing with a different browser or in incognito mode to rule out browser-specific issues.

Review Middleware:

Ensure that CsrfViewMiddleware and SessionMiddleware are correctly placed in your MIDDLEWARE setting.

Check CSRF Token Handling:

Make sure that the CSRF token is being handled correctly in your frontend application. You may need to manually set the X-CSRFToken header in your requests with the value of the CSRF token.

Debugging:

Use Django’s debugging tools to inspect the request and response objects. You can print out the request.COOKIES and response.cookies in your view to see what’s being set and sent.

I managed to change the localhost to be https instead of http, by creating an SSL certificate and adding this to my nuxt.config.js:
    https: {
      key: './server.key',
      cert: './server.crt'
    }
  }```
After changing the urls in the settings.py file to match the new https://localhost:3001 site (dunno why the port changed), the server started up fine and without error however after it started up I recieved this message:
`Listen failure: Couldn't listen on 127.0.0.1:8000: [Errno 98] Address already in use`

ok update, I managed to fix the lsiten failure by simply killing the network thing running on 127.... and now that I have a https localhost, with session_cookie_secure set to true and it being samesite none as well, I did a request and my request cookies contained the cookie: "tabstyle=raw-tab". But still no sessionid cookie.

Also would like to clarify, 2. Changed my browser settings to ensure any cross-site cookies are allowed, 3. The request has credentials: include, 4. I reviewed my settings and they are as they should apparently be, 5. The set-cookie header in the response has all the correct attributes that were set in the settings, 6. Tested in microsoft edge and got the same result, 7. I believe my middlewares are correctly ordered, 8. The csrf tokensiation, to my knowledge requires both x-csrftoken header and the csrf cookie, 9. I do not believe this is neccessary for the browser dev tools provide me enough
